# Pandas dataframe select entire rows with highest values from a specified column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to return the full row that contains the largest values out of a specified column. So let's say I create a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(25, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Then I'd have a table like this (sorry I can't get a proper table to form, so I just made a short one up):

```
A    B    C    D
14   67   35   22
75   21   34   64
```

And let's say it goes on for 25 rows like that. I want to take the top 5 largest values of column C and return those full rows.

If I do:

```
df['C'].nlargest()
```

it returns those 5 largest values, but I want it to return the full row.

I thought the below would work, but it gives me an error of "IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds":

```
df[df['C'].nlargest()]
```

I know this will be an easy solution for many people here, but it's stumped me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you want to use `columns` parameter:

```
In [53]: df.nlargest(5, columns=['C'])
Out[53]:
     A   B   C   D
17  43  91  95  32
18  13  36  81  56
7   61  90  76  85
16  68  21  73  68
14   3  64  71  59
```

Comment: Great work everyone! All the solutions work so it was hard to choose the best answer, but I went with this one since it was the easiest to read and understand and it used nlargest.

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1** One approach -

```
df.iloc[df.C.argsort()[::-1][:5]]
```

With simplified slicing, reduces to -

```
df.iloc[df.C.argsort()[:-6:-1]]
```

**Approach #2** For performance, if the order of those largest `n` rows is not important, we can also use `np.argpartition` -

```
df.iloc[df.C.values.argpartition(-5)[:-6:-1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

without using `nlargest`, by using `sort_values`

```
df.sort_values('C',ascending=False).iloc[:5,]
```

or using `head`

```
df.sort_values('C',ascending=False).head(5)
```

or using `quantile`

```
df[df.C>df.C.quantile(1-(5/len(df)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty

```
df.where(df.C.nlargest()).dropna()

       A     B     C     D
7   98.0  52.0  93.0  65.0
13  76.0  20.0  86.0  68.0
16  83.0   6.0  92.0  51.0
22  97.0  15.0  84.0   8.0
24  32.0  80.0  87.0  34.0
```

Comment: I'm not following?

Comment: I couldn't make this work (it raises a ValueError). Which version gave you that result?

Comment: python 2.7 and pandas 0.18.1